# Raspberry Pi NOOBS kit doesn't show operating systems at first boot

Tags: noobs

I just bought the Raspberry Pi [NOOBS](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs) kit, and at boot I got an error screen saying that it isn't connected to the Internet and so it can't load the OS images.

I can't press on *Quit* or *Install*.

How do I install the OS offline?

And how do I quit? So I can buy an Ethernet cable to connect it to the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can power off the Raspberry Pi without any issues at this point. You should take a look at *[NOOBS Setup | Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/)* on how to install your OS.

The direct link to the last NOOBS image (offline and network install) 
is http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS_latest.

Comment: It's worth clarifying here that there are *two* versions of NOOBS, one big one with all the OS images inside it, and one very little one (presumably this is what @sangino has) which is just able to download the other images.